# Is Google showing a wrong time in search result or is it Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, google, timestamps

Recently I answered a question and searched it on Google Search after 2mins, was curious to know how fast does it indexes...but was not able to find that question, searched it back after 10mins and I got that question in search results however it was showing wrong timing, so is it Stack Overflow or Google who is going wrong somewhere? Also it has 2 answers, result is showing 3...

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965753/how-can-i-open-multiple-links-using-a-single-anchor-tag/) to question

[image]

And Google Search result

[image]

Comment: Note, it _had_ two answers, one was just deleted (for the benefit of those that don't have 10k+ on SO)

Comment: @TinyTimPost Ya I just saw that than too, it counts 3...

Comment: Stack Overflow uses UTC, Google tries to use your system time

Answer (score 1):

Dates Google displays are:

- Guesses
- Cached

Inevitably there will be some out of date or incorrect data in search results.

Comment: guess in terms of answers too? or is it the StackOverflow micro-formats issue?